# Changing height of a jumbobox only when it needs to get bigger

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make the height of a jumbobox bigger according to the content (which depends on the user input). While that works I got the problem that it also shrinks if the content in it ain't much. The jumbobox is in a container.

How do I make it so that the the jumbobox only grows when needed, and shrinks back to a certain height when it doesn't need to be expanded? I tried to set `height` and `min-height` but that didn't work.

CSS:

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
}

#body
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow-y: auto; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#customcontainer3
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
#customjumbo4
{
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 7.5%;
}
```

Comment: html? - please provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my jumbo to this:

```
#customjumbo4
{
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 7.5%;
}
```

Now it works, took me a good day to figure it :/